# New to Django, unsure how to write queryset tying FK's together

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

For anyone frequenting the django tag, you may realize I am new to django (and haven't actually done development in a long time).

I am struggling with queries with the ORM.

I have two models, User & Department.  Department has a leader that is a FK to a user.

How do I return all instances of department and its associated first & last name of the user?

Something like:

```
SELECT Department.dept, User.first_name, User.last_name 
FROM Departments, Users
WHERE Department.leader = User.Id OR Department.leader = NULL
```

Thanks for any help, my mind is just not accepting thinking of queries in terms of the ORM yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I return all instances of department and its associated first & last name of the user?

Well you can access the `leader` of `some_department` with `some_department.leader`. If you however want to *annotate* every department that way (for example because you need fast access to these fields), you could write:

```
from django.db.models import F

Department.objects.annotate(
    first_name=F('leader__first_name')
    last_name=F('leader__last_name')
)
```

This will return `Department` instances, but where every `departement` has two extra attributes, `first_name` and `last_name` that contain the `first_name` and `last_name` of the corresponding leader.

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT department.*,
       user.first_name AS first_name,
       user.last_name AS last_name
FROM departement
LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON department.leader_id = user.id
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That did what I want... perhaps not the great epiphany i was after, understanding still alludes me a bit.  Thanks for your help!  :)